# Is there a way of making my code check if the number entered is under 10?

Tags: python, numbers

so lets say my code was

```
age = input('How Old Are You?')
```

would there be a way to check if the answer is under a certain number?

Comment: Yes, there is. What code have you tried to detect that?

Answer (score 1):

```py
if int(age) < 10:
    print("age is less than 10")
```

Perhaps something like this?